# Nuitka: Failed to acquire lock Local

Tags: python, nuitka

I tried to use Nuitka to pack my python project.

I executed this command in my anaconda environment.

```
python -m nuitka --standalone --show-memory --show-progress --follow-imports --nofollow-import-to=util --output-dir=out --include-data-dir=mdf=mdf --windows-icon-from-ico=./blur.ico --enable-plugin=numpy,pyside2 blur_exe.py
```

It seems everything went well during PASS 1 and PASS 2 stage. But I ran into issue at last in the Backend C stage.

```
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: cl (cl 14.2).
Backend C: 80.3%|████████████████████     | 1318/1642scons: *** [module.torch.optim._multi_tensor._functional.obj] CacheLockException : Failed to acquire lock Local\C--Users-JHU3SZH-AppData-Local-Nuitka-Nuitka-Cache-clcache-objects-bce after 10000ms; try setting CLCACHE_OBJECT_CACHE_TIMEOUT_MS environment variable to a larger value.
scons: *** [module.torch.optim._multi_tensor.adamw.obj] CacheLockException : Failed to acquire lock Local\C--Users-JHU3SZH-AppData-Local-Nuitka-Nuitka-Cache-clcache-objects-fb5 after 10000ms; try setting CLCACHE_OBJECT_CACHE_TIMEOUT_MS environment variable to a larger value.
scons: *** [module.torch.optim._multi_tensor.adadelta.obj] CacheLockException : Failed to acquire lock Local\C--Users-JHU3SZH-AppData-Local-Nuitka-Nuitka-Cache-clcache-objects-000 after 10000ms; try setting CLCACHE_OBJECT_CACHE_TIMEOUT_MS environment variable to a larger value.
scons: *** [module.torch.optim._multi_tensor.adagrad.obj] CacheLockException : Failed to acquire lock Local\C--Users-JHU3SZH-AppData-Local-Nuitka-Nuitka-Cache-clcache-objects-000 after 10000ms; try setting CLCACHE_OBJECT_CACHE_TIMEOUT_MS environment variable to a larger value.
```

I thought it might because some folder was opened. So I closed the related programs and tried again. But errors were still there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I restarted my laptop, and tried packing once again. The error is gone.